# Azure CLI "az ams job start" is returning "index out of range"

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-media-services

I need to automate the creation of Assets, the uploading of MP3 files and the running Jobs in Azure Media Services.

I have successfully created Azure CLI scripts to create Assets and upload the MP3 files into those assets.

However, when I create a Job using the "az ams job start" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ams/job?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ams-job-start) command it returns with

"list index out of range"

If I run the same command in the Azure portal, it returns with the same error message.

The paramaters that I am using are of this format.

```
az ams job start --account-name myaccount --input-asset-name "myinputasset" --files "myfile.mp3" --transform-name "mytransform" --output-assets "myoutputasset" --resource-group "mygroup" --name "myname"
```

Can anyone provide any hints as to what I have done wrong or how I can get more details about what I need to do differently?  The documentation is not great and I feel I have tried every combination of settings to get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the command is failing is because you are missing an "=" sign after the `--output-asset` parameter. To clarify, this is how the CLI says the `--output-asset` parameter should be formatted:

```
--output-assets [Required] : Space-separated assets in 'assetName=label' format. An asset without label can be sent like this: 'assetName='.
```

To get the command to work change the command from `--output-assets "myoutputasset"` to `--output-assets "myoutputasset="`

Sorry about the error message, it is definitely not helpful. I have submitted a PR to update the error message to something more useful, thanks!

Comment: Clearly I misread the documentation, but it is a pretty weird format that is needed.  Why is the "=" needed at all?  I was new to AMS and was quite lost during the learning curve. I had no idea what a "label" was and will never use it.  I suspect many others will come down the same path as me.  Thanks for the help BTW! :)